# What is the best way to check if there are 4 items vertically horizontaly or diagonaly which end the game of connect 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import random
#initializacija programa in delovanja
rezultat = {
    'a':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'b':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'c':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'd':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "]
}


def izpis():
    tabela = ['+-1-+-2-+-3-+-4-+', 
    'a %s| %s| %s| %s|' %(rezultat['a'][0],rezultat['a'][1],rezultat['a'][2],rezultat['a'][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'b %s| %s| %s| %s|' %(rezultat['b'][0],rezultat['b'][1],rezultat['b'][2],rezultat['b'][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'c %s| %s| %s| %s|' %(rezultat['c'][0],rezultat['c'][1],rezultat['c'][2],rezultat['c'][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+',
    'd %s| %s| %s| %s|' %(rezultat['d'][0],rezultat['d'][1],rezultat['d'][2],rezultat['d'][3]),
    '+---+---+---+---+']
    [print(i) for i in tabela]

def restart():
    return {
    'a':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'b':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'c':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "],
    'd':["  ", "  ", "  ","  "]
    }
```

This is what i have done so far. It draws out the table. I dont know how i would check if the game is over. So the game is over when 4 are connected vertically, horizontaly or diagonaly. What is the best way i can check if the game is over?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Is the size of your field restricted to 4x4? Or will it vary?. The obvious solution is to hard code all possible fields which end the game, e.g. `(('a',0),('a',1),('a',2),('a',3), ...)` and check equality of those fields.

Comment: I have tried with if statements but its just a big mess and also there should be a feature that you can play 5x5 so i do also need to implament that. Btw this is for a school project that we have to figure out on our own.

Comment: @SimonFink i know how to do the horizontal check so if the elements on index i are the same or if all of the elements in one of those lists are the same. What would be the best way to check if list a0 is the same as 10 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found this solution:

```
[r[i] for i, r in enumerate(board)]
```